# First value twice when using unique filtering (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have made a very simple Visual Basic script, which uses the advanced filter function in Excel, to copy unique values from a column in one sheet, to a column in a different sheet. It works fine on all values, except the first which appears twice. Can anyone tell me the reason for this glitch? I tried using the filter manually, with the same result.

```
Sub getUniqueRuns()

    Sheets(2).Range("C2:C65536").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, 
    CopyToRange:=Sheets(5).Range("A2"), Unique:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AdvancedFilter is using the top row of your range as the title and then providing distict values from the rest of the range. As you have provided row 2 as the first row, it is using this as the header and then rows 3 onwards as the data. As a result you are getting duplicates. I suggest you change your ranges to the below which will then copy the heading across.

```
Sub getUniqueRuns()
    Sheets(2).Cells.Clear
    Sheets(2).Range("C1:C65536").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, 
    CopyToRange:=Sheets(5).Range("A1"), Unique:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Sheets(2).Range("C1") contains the header of the column (a String). The same header is located in Sheets(5).Range("A1"). If I try to include them, the way you did, I get a "Runttime Error 1004: The extract range has a missing or illegal field name"

Comment: I made it work, after having clear the sheet that I am copying to. Maybe you could add this to your answer, in case other people had the same issue. None-the-less, it was the correct answer, so thanks :-)

Comment: Sheets(2).Cells.Clear added. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a script of mine, I resolved it with a .offset(1) to offset the extra row in rgData.

```
Sub modHouse_Popularity()
'
' modHouse_Popularity Macro
' Select Houses and remove duplicates

'define range
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Popularity").Range("A2:A500")

 'retain header
    rg.Offset(1).ClearContents
    
'define data fields, criteria fields and out put fields
    Dim rgData As Range, rgCriteria As Range, rgOutput As Range
    Set rgData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Facade requests").Range("Table1[House]").Offset(1)
    Set rgCriteria = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Popularity").Range("a2")
    Set rgOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Popularity").Range("a3:a500")
'place data

    rgData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rgCriteria, rgOutput, True
```